# How many words can be formed using two letters "a", four letters "u" and 3 more?

Tags: combinatorics

How many words can be formed using two letters "a", four letters "u" and 3 more?

My attempt: a combination could be "aauuuuxyz", where x, y or z can be chosen between 26 letters. I think the order is not relevant, because the first two "a" could be permuted, so I would think that our case is combination. But with the last three letters (x, y or z) the order is relevant. So it seems difficult to me to see how to do it.

Comment: Are the "3 more" distinct from $a$ and $u?$

Comment: each one of these 3 more letters can vary between 26 letters, included "a" and "u"

Comment: To rephrase, are you asking how many nine letter words contain at least two $a$s and at least four $u$s?

Comment: yes, that is what I am asking

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to use exponential generating functions,

find the coefficient of $x^9$ in

$9! (\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!})(\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{ 5!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^7}{7!})(x^0 +x +\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!})^{24}$,

[wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coefficient+of+x%5E9+in++9%21%28x%5E2%2F2%21+%2Bx%5E3%2F3%21+%2Bx%5E4%2F4%21+%2Bx%5E5%2F5%21%29%28x%5E4%2F4%21%2Bx%5E5%2F5%21%2Bx%5E6%2F6%21%2Bx%5E7%2F7%21%29%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2F2%21%2Bx%5E3%2F3%21%29%5E24) gives the answer  $18613092$

---

**PS:**

A bit of explanation on exponential g.f. use here

- Were all $9$ letters distinct, we would have $9!$ permutations, but they aren't
- The first term represents that there **have** to be two $a's$ which can be permuted in $2!$ ways, hence $x^2/2!$ and can be at most $5 a's$ (as there are already four $u's$) and so on.
- the last term represents zero to three from the remaining $24$ letters of the alphabet

Answer (score 2):

There are $10$ possibilities for the three unspecified letters as $i$ a's, $j$ u's and $k$ not-a-or-u's. For each case the number of possibilities can be counted as $\binom9{2+i,4+j,k}24^k$ where a multinomial coefficient is used, which upon summing gives the answer as $18613092$.

Answer (score 0):

The word shuold be like "aauuuu???" .

The possible cases of "???" are:

1. $xyz$
2. $uxy$ and $axy$
3. $uux$ and $aax$ and $axx$ and $uxx$
4. $uuu$ and $aaa$ and $uaa$ and $uua$
5. $xxx$ and $xxy$

And then we can bombine the possible cases separately with the possible cases of "a"s and "u"s:

1. $24 \times 23 \times 22 \times 3! \times C^2_9 \times C^4_7$
2. $24 \times 23 \times 2! \times C^2_9 \times C^5_7 + 24 \times 23 \times 2! \times C^3_9 \times C^4_6$
3. $24 \times C^6_9 \times C^2_3 + 24 \times C^4_9 \times C^4_5 + 24 \times C^5_9 \times C^2_4 + 24 \times C^4_9 \times C^3_5$
4. $C^7_9 + C^5_9 + C^4_9 + C^6_9$
5. $24 \times C^3_9 \times C^2_6 + 24 \times 23  \times 2 \times C^2_9 \times C^4_7 \times C^2_3$

Then we should add them all to get the final answer.